# Change default sort order for Spring Data findAll() method

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA and I wonder if it is possible to change the default sort order for a entity being used by the Spring Data `findAll()` method?

Comment: Write you own JPA query for that.

Comment: @Andrei yes but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: The findAll doesn't have any ordering applied. If you want this changed you would have to extend `SimpleJpaRepository` and override the `findAll` method. See the section on [Adding custom behavior to all repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories). You can also use this to override to default behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to do this by either:

in spring-data 1.5+, overriding the findAll() method in your Interface, adding the @Query annotation and creating a named Query in your Entity class like, for example, below:

Entity

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query="select u from User u order by u.address.town")
public class User{

}
```

Repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends ... <User, Long> {

    @Override
    @Query
    public Iterable<User> findAll();
}
```

or,

by creating a custom repository implementation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Answer (score 38):

You can achieve this as follows:

```
dao.findAll(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "colName"));
// or
dao.findAll(Sort.by("colName").descending());
```

Another way to achieve the same. Use the below method name:

```
findByOrderByIdAsc()
```

Comment: Yes this would be an option. However I would like the standard findAll() method to use a specific order. The reason is I'm using @Cacheable on it as well.

Comment: Could you please try this method name - `findByOrderByIdAsc()`

Comment: Yes I understand I can use this. But I wonder if it's possible to in general set default sorting for entity. I guess not.

Comment: The solution I have posted above does what you need.

Comment: It only does what he needs for a single method.

Comment: Hi. Is the signature 'findByOrderByIdAsc' correct? Does it select ALL records sorted by Id? it looks like smth  is missing after the 1st By

Comment: Actually it's frustrating that this thing can be implemented in so many ways: HQL, findAll(Sort), by adding OrderBy to method name, by implementing PageableAndSortable ... so which one is better?

Answer (score 2):

Use a PagingAndSortingRepository instead.
With that in place you can add a queryparameter ?sort=,

Repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {
  //no custom code needed
}
```

GET Request:

```
localhost:8080/users?sort=name,desc
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add costom query to findAll() jpa query you can do it this way

here i changed my default order

According to my default order is primary key it is id

but now i here set id_order to change my default order

**Model class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@NamedQuery(name = "Category.findAll", query="select u from Category u order by 
u.id_order")
public class Category {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
private String nameEn;
private String nameSi;
private String nameTa;
private Integer id_order;
```

**Repository class**

```
import com.model.Category;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface CategoryRepository extends CrudRepository<Category, Integer> {

@Override
@Query
public Iterable<Category> findAll();
```