# Spring Data JpaRepository findAll(Iterable<ID> ids) + findAll(Sort sort)

Tags: java, spring, sorting, spring-data-jpa

With Spring Data JpaRepository is there any capability to get select collection of given Id with some sorting. That mean I need to make enable following query. I have found some [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031028/change-default-sort-order-for-spring-data-findall-method) apply with @NamedQuery but I can't make enable it because I am using **Spring-data-jap 1.4.2.RELEASE**. Thanks.

```
public Iterable<User> findAll(Iterable<Integer> userIds) {

 Sort sort = new Sort(Direction.ASC, "name");

 Iterable<User> users = userRepository.findAll(userIds, sort); 

 return users; 
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just declare a query method like this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, Integer> {

  Iterable<User> findByIdIn(Collection<Integer> ids, Sort sort);
}
```