# How to Use sorting in Spring Data Rest GET method

Tags: spring, rest, sorting, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

When I create any repository in spring framework like following it gives method by default to get all records of the entity using this API

GET : http://localhost:3000/api/addresses

It sends data from ascending order But If I want my data in descending order than How can I specify this ?

**Address Repository**

```
    public interface AddressRepository extends JpaRepository<Address, Long> 

    {
    }
```

Comment: If it is findAll, then you can override this and add a condition for order by in your query

Comment: @CrazyMac My Query ? NO :| 
I didn't write any Query it is Spring default call to get records

Comment: What is your front end. Are you using Angular ? If yes, then you can use orderBy : 'name' as an approach to sort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also specify this as part of your request, take a look at documentation here [Sorting](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#paging-and-sorting.sorting).

Also please take a look at similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031028/change-default-sort-order-for-spring-data-findall-method).

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps,you can :

```
localhost:3000/api/addresses?sort={property},desc
```

this will help you sort by property desc

Comment: it will work for you.localhost:3000/api/addresses?sort=id,desc   that will sorted by the property of id desc

Answer (score 0):

Try inside the AddressRepository class something like:

```
public List<Address> findAllByOrderByIdDesc();
```

of course you can change the "ById" part with any other field you want to use for sorting.

Comment: I know all these methods :\ I don't want to write any method just 
wants to modify 

GET : http://localhost:3000/api/addresses this query so that get records in desc order