# Spring JPA order by in entity class

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I am using Spring Data JPA. Is it possible to use order by at entity level, as we do at collection level

```
// collection order
@OrderBy("name ASC")
List <Foo> fooList;
```

I would like to specify order by at entity level

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity" )
// annotation to order by ordinalNo
@Where(clause = "deleted = 0")
public class Entity 
private Integer ordinalNo;
```

Comment: Is it what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031028/change-default-sort-order-for-spring-data-findall-method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change default sort order for Spring Data findAll() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031028/change-default-sort-order-for-spring-data-findall-method)